# SharePoint Online List Items Using Old Version of Workflow

Tags: workflow, office-365, designer-workflow

I am currently working with SharePoint Online however I have an issue. I currently have a list with over 300 items in and I have made a major update to the workflow.

The issue is that the list items are still using the old version of the workflow. I have removed the old instances of the workflow from within the workflow settings, however list items are continuing to use the previous version. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In flight workflows do not pick up changes made to the workflow. They must be stopped and restarted in order for the change to be realized.

Comment: Is there a quick way of doing this with SharePoint Online?

Comment: You may have to write a console app, using CSOM try to terminate all the running workflows for the older instance.